# Hide twitter button when followed

Tags: javascript, twitter

Simple question, i want to hide the twitter follow button when someone is already following me.

I have problem with people who unfollow me because of double click :o

here is the origial twitter button

```
<a class="twitter-follow-button"
href="https://twitter.com/mamariaford"
data-show-count="false"
data-lang="en">
Follow @twitterdev
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src= "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code to detect events, full documentation here https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
        twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event){
            // hide button
        });
        twttr.events.bind('follow', function(event){
            // hide button
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter button fires an event ([documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events)) you can bind to:

```
twttr.events.bind(
  'follow',
  function (event) {
    // hide the button here
  }
);
```